# Definition of built in redundancy

Tags: entropy, huffman-code

Assume that we have 3 bit ascii representation. How can I get the built in redundancy of that representation? I searched internet for days. But still couldn't find something relevant. It will be grate if someone can explain me what is "built in redundancy" means as well.

Thank you.

Comment: You searched the Internet for *days* but still couldn't find a definition for redundancy? Is Google blocked in your country?

Comment: @CodyGray. Sorry Seems you misunderstand my question. I don't need to know what redundancy is. What I asked is what is "Built in redundancy of ascii representation"? And what it means by the terms with huffman.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, redundancy is the difference between the number of bits used to transmit a message and the entropy of the message.